# ElementRef is undefined

Tags: angular, focus, angular-ng-if, elementref

I’m working in an angular 6 application. I have a textarea that I’d like to give focus to as soon as the page loads. I’m not able to do so.

Here is what the page looks like:

```
<div fxLayoutAlign="begin">
  <button mat-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/Administration']">
    <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i> Back to Administration
  </button>
</div>
    <div class="app-loading" *ngIf="_loading">
      <mat-spinner diameter=100></mat-spinner>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!_loading">

    <div class="knowledgeBody">

      <div *ngIf="_mode === 'view'">
        {{ _knowledgeText }}
        <div fxLayoutAlign="end">
          <button mat-button (click)="edit_clicked()" disabled="{{ _knowledgeText.trim().length === 0 }}">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="_mode !== 'view'">
        <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="_knowledgeText" cdkTextareaAutosize #knowledgeTextarea>
          {{ _knowledgeText }}
        </textarea>

        <div fxLayoutAlign="end">
          <button mat-button (click)="save_clicked()" disabled="{{ _knowledgeText.trim().length === 0 }}">
            <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The textarea of interest is #knowledgeTextarea.

Here’s the component for the page:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-knowledge',
  templateUrl: './knowledge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./knowledge.component.scss']
})
export class KnowledgeComponent implements OnInit {

  private _mode : string;
  private _loading : boolean;
  private _knowledgeId : string;
  private _knowledgeText : string;
  private _description : string;
  private _groupPK : string;

  @ViewChild('knowledgeTextarea') knowledgeTextarea : ElementRef;

  constructor(private _activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute,
    private _watermelonService : WatermelonService,
    private _logService : LoggingService,
    private _dialog: MatDialog) {
      this._loading = true;
    }

  ngOnInit() {
…
    this.knowledgeTextarea.nativeElement.focus();
…
  }
…
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property ‘nativeElement’ of undefined.
```

I’ve read that this can happen when you reference an element on the page using the # identification (#knowledgeTextarea) inside an *ngIf block. So this…

```
  <div *ngIf="_mode !== 'view'">
    <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="_knowledgeText" cdkTextareaAutosize #knowledgeTextarea>
      {{ _knowledgeText }}
    </textarea>
</div>
```

…will not work.

But then what is the alternative?

I tried this…

```
  <div *ngIf="_mode !== 'view'">
    <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="_knowledgeText" cdkTextareaAutosize #knowledgeTextarea>
      {{ _knowledgeText }}
    </textarea>
    {{ knowledgeTextarea.focus() }}
</div>
```

…which worked but then I got a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, which JB Nizet told me not to do here: [Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529454/getting-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error).

If there is another way of doing this, please let me know. All I want is to be able to give the textarea focus when the page loads. Any way of accomplishing that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543714/how-can-i-use-viewchildren-to-get-multiple-native-elements-using-template-variab) may help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is accessing the element before it was rendered.  You must ensure that the content is rendered before it is being used. So instead of accessing it inside `ngOnInit`, you should do in `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
 @ViewChild('knowledgeTextarea') knowledgeTextarea: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.knowledgeTextarea.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Working sample is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjyfwf